# Elasticsearch works fine in localhost, but gives connection error while testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, elasticsearch, rspec, chewy-gem

I'm new to Elasticsearch and Docker. I'm getting search results with my application, But when I run test against the same , I'm getting connection error like this

```
cannot assign requested address - cannot assign requested address - connect(2) for "localhost" port 9200 (localhost:9200)
```

I'm using `chewy gem` of `ruby on rails` to implement `Elasticsearch`

here is the sample code of search

```
result = TestIndex::Test
                     .filter(match: { test_id: testid })
                     .query(something
                      })
                     .highlight({something
                                  }
                                })
                   .paginate(page: page, per_page: page_size).as_json
```

I'm testing using `Rspec`
Note that search is working fine in application. This error occurs when running the test file

Comment: Are you sure elesticserach is up and running when you are running Rspec?

Comment: Also in test environment it should access elesticserach at port 2950 instead of 2900 to keep the data intact between test and development environment